# How to use two.js in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript, visual-studio, import

I am using Visual Studio to write a ASP.NET MVC web application. I am also quite new to TypeScript, but I know C# and JavaScript so I don't have issues with the syntax.

However I am completely confused with importing/referencing **.js files**, namely for the [two.js](https://github.com/jonobr1/two.js) library:

One of the files ([`two.module.js`](https://github.com/jonobr1/two.js/blob/dev/build/two.module.js)) seems to be annotated with JSDoc and ends with:

```
export default (this || window).Two;
```

so I am presuming it should be importable as an ES6 module, but how does this work with TypeScript?

I tried using this:

```
import { Two } from "../twojs/twojs.module.js"
```

but I get an error (cannot find module `"../twojs/twojs.module.js"`, presumably because it's not a .ts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to import it like this if you installed it into `node_modules`. The Typescript compiler will resolve the module by finding it in the node_modules folder.

Because it is a default export, you must omit the brackets here.

```
import Two from "two.js"
```

Comment: Thanks, omitting brackets fixed the problem! I think I'll have to read the TypeScript docs a bit more carefully to get a better idea of how this works.